# Springboot catch hibernate errors

Tags: hibernate, interceptor

I have an API back in java springboot jpa
I try to catch all the errors, what I manage to do

but I would also like to catch hibernate errors whose messages are much clearer.
is it possible ? and how to do it?

thank you

Comment: Spring wraps Hibernate exceptions into [`DataAccessException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html). Just catch that exception wherever you want (in service or in `@ControllerAdvice`).

Comment: thanks but the error messages are the same as spring, I don't get the hibernate messages

Comment: Then you should post some example of what you tried, what you got and what you want/need. The error message in `DataAccessException` should be the same as the Hibernate exception, or if you want you could use `.getMostSpecificCause()` to get the Hibernate exception that is wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate will throws exception of it's own. But if you want clearer exception message from hibernate it's not possible because hibernate exception message are fixed. Somehow or somewhere in the code if you can catch the exception and write your custom exception class with your custom exception message or clearer message.

Comment: thank you, it's a shame because hibernate errors indicate where exactly the error is while spring just indicates an error ... For maintenance it is less easy.